# was working great, now all foam

Tags: foam

I'm a beer keg newbie. I'm on my third keg and i am still having problems. I tapped the keg on Christmas Day after leaving it for 24 hours. Temp is 39, pressure is 12 running a 5ft line. It poured great for the first day, with the occasional foamy pull. The next day we noticed the keg was leaking from the coupler. I cleaned it up reconnected the coupler and had little pressure. I added an o ring and let it sit. The pressure came back and it doesn't leak, but every pull is 90% foam. I let it sit for another day, dropping the pressure to 10 and releasing the pressure value on the coupler. Still foam...what gives...it was working well.
Can anyone give me some suggestions.

Comment: What kind of keg? Same keg every time or three different kegs? Did it leak beer or CO2? Filtered beer or yeasty homebrew?

Comment: All different kegs. 2 purchased from the Ontario beer store (bud light) and 1 purchased from a Craft brewer (Beau's). The last couple of times it has leaked beer from the coupler. At least half an ounce a hour from my estimation. It was working well until the leak, and when i take the o ring out now, it is still foamy.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation as you. I fixed it by venting the keg completely, then sealing everything up and attaching the gas line. I left the pressure off at first though. I slowly rolled it up to about two pounds and poured. I continued to increase the pressure very slowly and now keep it around 8 pounds. It sounds like you are over pressurized when serving.

Comment: I would agree with you.  The 2nd beer I put on tap was very temperamental and one thing I had to realize was that the setting on the regulator was the pressure of CO2 in the empty space of the keg, not necessarily the carbonation of the beer or even how much CO2 is coming out the tank.  Plus when you change the setting, it takes many hours to stabilize.  Also figure out some way to insulate the tap tower if you have one.  Warm beer in the upper foot of the tube has caused me lot of grief in the past.

Comment: To follow on Sloloem's comment about cooling the tap tower, a quick and relatively painless method is the one illustrated in [this Popular Mechanics article](http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/improvement/interior/fighting-foam-how-to-insulate-a-kegerator-draft-tower-16554310). It has worked very well for me and only took about 15 minutes of actual work.